# Find N number subset in Array that sum to 0 [Subset Sum problem, that returns the subset]

Tags: arrays, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to practice the interview question in the title

For those who directly want to know my question , jump to **"Smaller version of my Question"** .

For more context , read on.

=>For N = 2, 
We can simply use a Map.

=>For N= 3, 
there is a n^2 solution : [Finding three elements in an array whose sum is closest to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070359/finding-three-elements-in-an-array-whose-sum-is-closest-to-an-given-number)
[Check the accepted answer, it actually give you a solution for sum to 0 , rather than upto as in title of the link]

I guess using the above link, we can have 3 pointers for N=4 and get a n^3 solution.

Anyways, the point I am making that eventually all these solutions are not going to scale as N grows. So I am looking for a general purpose solution

I think this can be derived from a subset sum problem [Subset sum problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708436/subset-sum-problem) . However the solution [dynamic programming version] to this problem returns a boolean. I am looking to get the  actual subset.
The boolean solution itself isn't completely natural to derive [in the sense you cant 'derive' the answer easily unless you have read it.. I had to write down an example to understand it]. Anyways, I am looking for a way to modify it to give me a subset rather than just a boolean.

**Smaller version of my Question:**
Modify this to return the actual subset than just the boolean

```
Let S[i] = true if we can make sum i and false otherwise.

S[0] = true // we can always make sum 0: just don't choose any number
S[i] = false for all i != 0
for each number i in your input
    for s = MaxSum downto i
        if ( S[s - i] == true )
            S[s] = true; // if we can make the sum s - i, we can also make the sum s by adding i to the sum s - i.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `S[s]` contain the list of numbers that make that sum when it is possible:

```
Let S[i] = the list of numbers that make up that sum and false (or null, something distinct from an empty list) otherwise.

S[0] = empty list // we can always make sum 0: just don't choose any number
S[i] = null for all i != 0
for each number i in your input
    for s = MaxSum downto i
        if ( S[s - i] != null )
            S[s] = S[s-i] with i added; // if we can make the sum s - i, we can also make the sum s by adding i to the sum s - i.
```

Comment: thanks .. very elegant. So basically my S structure in java would be List<int[]> .

Comment: Except I think Java doesn't let you mix collections and generic arrays, so `int[][]` or `List<List<Integer>>`