# Subset sum for exactly k integers?

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

Following from these question [Subset sum problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708436/subset-sum-problem)  and [Sum-subset with a fixed subset size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size) I was wondering what the general algorithm for solving a subset sum problem, where we are forced to use EXACTLY k integers, k <= n.

Evgeny Kluev mentioned that he would go for using optimal for k = 4 and after that use brute force approach for k- 4 and optimal for the rest. Anyone could enlight what he means by a brute force approach here combined with optimal k=4 algo?

Perhaps someone knows a better, general solution?

Comment: Do you need to apply the algorithm multiple times? or just on one set of numbers? If it's just one set of numbers I suggest you manually play around with the numbers to see what patterns, sparsity etc they have

Comment: Well, I need to fin it only once, but it is still non-trvial. You need to ensure that you take exactly k elements from the array, hence my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original dynamic programming algorithm applies, with a slight extension - in addition to remembering partial sums, you also need to remember number of ints used to get the sums.

In the original algorithm, assuming the target sum is `M` and there are `n` integers, you fill a boolean `n` x `M` array `A`, where `A[i,m]` is true iff sum `m` can be achieved by picking (any number of) from first `i+1` ints (assuming indexing from 0).

You can extend it to a three dimensional array `n`x`M`x`k`, which has a similar property - `A[i,m,l]` is true iff, sum `m` can be achieved by picking exactly `l` from first `i+1` ints.

Assuming the ints are in array `j[0..n-1]`:

The recursive relation is pretty similar - the field `A[0,j[0],1]`  is true (you pick `j[0]`, getting sum `j[0]` with 1 int (duh)), other fields in `A[0,*,*]` are false and deriving fields in `A[i+1,*,*]` from `A[i,*,*]` is also similar to the original algorithm: `A[i+1,m,l]` is true if `A[i,m,l]`is true (if you can pick `m` from first `i` ints, then obviously you can pick `m` from first `i+1` ints) or if `A[i, m - j[i+1], l-1]` is true (if you pick `j[i+1]` then you increase the sum by `j[i+1]` and the number of ints by 1).

If `k` is small then obviously it makes sense to skip all of the above part and just iterate over all combinations of `k` ints and checking their sums. `k<=4` indeed seems like a sensible threshold.

Comment: I wonder how the above compare to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size/8926458#comment12539828_8926458