# Looking for an alternative to this array solution

Tags: c#, arrays

I have array of int[10000].

I need to sum each int with other one, and show result, for only those, where sum are > N.

Sum, can be any with any element of array, also sum of 5,6,7...10000 elements of array which > N.

I can write down(all combinations, but it`s insane) it like a[1] + a[2] + a[3]... But may be there are other resolution?

I need result all combinations, that gives me sum which is >N

Okey. If it is array of int[10]?

Comment: "each int with other one"... sorry, can you clarify? are you looking for a 10000x10000 compare of `a[x]+a[y]`, testing each pair for > N? or what? what is the thing being summed? the entire array? all pairs? all triples? all combinations? or...?

Comment: This seems like homework, in that you have defined a problem but show no solution. Homework has been deprecated here, and is not valid as a question. Please write up your attempt to create a solution to this problem and then ask a question if you get stuck or encounter a technical issue in your program.

Comment: Have you tried something?What should be the output when you find a sum that is greater than N?

Comment: All combinations. I think the best is to use Combinatorics theorems...

Comment: @user1763833 you want to use all combinations on a 10,000 array? er.... have you done the math to see how large that is? It is *quite staggeringly* large.

Comment: What are you trying to do, really? There are around 2*10^3010 combinations that you can make of the numbers in the array, so you can't test them all. All the combined computer power in the world couldn't do that in your lifetime...

Comment: @Guffa I'm thinking more like "universal heat death" ;p Also: what calculator do you use? most of my usual "go to" apps died for that!

Comment: @MarcGravell: calc.exe in Windows 8...

Comment: @Guffa that's odd... I'm on win 8 x64, and it just says "Overflow". Or did you use logarithms?

Comment: @MarcGravell: There are 2^10000 possible combinations (except a few that should be excluded, i.e. the one with none of the items, and all of the ones with only a single item, so that's 10001 to subtract, but that won't make a noticable difference to the result).

Comment: @Guffa dammit, I'm a bit-shitfter at core, and it didn't occur to me to think of it as a bit mask. Which is odd, 'cos whenever I've implemented manually, I've done it **exactly** as a bitmask!

Comment: Okey... if Array is int[10]... ?

Comment: @user1763833: Then there are only 2^10 combinations, i.e. 1024 (minus the 11 ones that have zero or one items). You can check them all in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Guffa: I need to know, all variants where >N. Like Result: a[1] + a[5], a[1] + a[5] + a[6]. Not only possible combinations.

Comment: Even at n = 10 this is nasty.

Comment: @TravisJ at n=10, I wouldn't blink at it - I'd just implement it. Probably brute force (nothing clever)

Comment: @TravisJ: Yeap.. But "R" statistics can do this..

Comment: There are 10000! possible combinations.  Factorial, that's a Big Number.  Self-training on the limits of computability is difficult if it isn't obvious.

Comment: @user1763833: Just loop through the possible combinations and calculate the sum for each, and keep the ones that you like.

Comment: @Guffa: So i need, to write in my code, all possible combinations? Not the best way...

Comment: @HansPassant: But a[1]+a[2] is the same as a[2]+a[1], so you get a lot of duplicates. When you have elliminated those, there are only 2^10000-10001 combinations left.

Comment: @user1763833: That depends on what you want to do. That's the simplest way, so that is the best way in one aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708436/subset-sum-problem) you can find two solutions for this algorithm. The only change is you have to track your numbers whose sum is greater that N and you need to repeat it for all possibilities instead of just finding true/false result.