# Algorithm for finding a group of numbers in a list that equal a target

Tags: c#, algorithm

So here is what I'm trying to do. I have a list of integers:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() {5,7,12,8,7};
```

And I also got a target:

```
int target = 20;
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to create a new list of integer that when added together equal my target. So if my target is `20`, I need a list like this:

```
{ 12, 8 }
```

If my target is 26, then I'll have this:

```
{ 7, 12, 7 }
```

Each number can only be used one time (7 is used twice because its in the list twice). If there is no solution, it should return an empty list. Anyone have any idea how I can do something like this?

Comment: If there are multiple possibilities, do you need to provide all of them, or just the first match?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - Providing them all would be stellar. I guess it would return an array of `List<int>`'s?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subset sum problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708436/subset-sum-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a statistical problem.  You want to find all possible combinations with a matching sum. I can recommend this project which is also worth reading:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

Then it's easy and efficient:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 5, 7, 12, 8, 7 };
var allMatchingCombos = new List<IList<int>>();
for (int lowerIndex = 1; lowerIndex < myList.Count; lowerIndex++)
{
    IEnumerable<IList<int>> matchingCombos = new Combinations<int>(myList, lowerIndex, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition)
        .Where(c => c.Sum() == 20);
    allMatchingCombos.AddRange(matchingCombos);
}

foreach(var matchingCombo in allMatchingCombos)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", matchingCombo));
```

Output:

```
12,8
5,7,8
5,8,7
```

Comment: just my opinion, would not it helps if we sort the list before taking all possible sums. we can exit the loops if the sum is greater than target.

Comment: This is really only "efficient" when the source list pretty small.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: there are better algorithms for sure but it might be fast enough. "Efficient" and "large" are also subjective. Maybe there's also a way to optimze the approach above. I've just used the first that came to my mind. @Miller: if the order matters you should use `Variations`.

Comment: Could you please add the Combinations object to your code sample

Comment: This is excellent, but like   Austin Salonen said, it work well in small list  like 20 max

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the solutions given below here: https://github.com/Mr-Zoidberg/Find-Possible-Combinations

**1. Using recursion**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int target = 20;
        var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 9 };

        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Combinations: {SumCounter(numbers, target)}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static int SumCounter(IReadOnlyList<int> numbers, int target)
    {
        var result = 0;
        RecursiveCounter(numbers, target, new List<int>(), ref result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void RecursiveCounter(IReadOnlyList<int> numbers, int target, List<int> partial, ref int result)
    {
        var sum = partial.Sum();
        if (sum == target)
        {
            result++;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" + ", partial.ToArray()) + " = " + target);
        }

        if (sum >= target) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            var remaining = new List<int>();
            for (var j = i + 1; j < numbers.Count; j++) remaining.Add(numbers[j]);
            var partRec = new List<int>(partial) { numbers[i] };
            RecursiveCounter(remaining, target, partRec, ref result);
        }
    }
```

**2. Get subsets using Linq**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int target = 20;
        var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 9 };

        var matches = numbers.GetSubsets().Where(s => s.Sum() == target).ToArray();

        foreach (var match in matches) Console.WriteLine(match.Select(m => m.ToString()).Aggregate((a, n) => $"{a} + {n}") + $" = {target}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Combinations: {matches.Length}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetSubsets<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (!collection.Any()) return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);
        var element = collection.Take(1);
        var ignoreFirstSubsets = GetSubsets(collection.Skip(1));
        var subsets = ignoreFirstSubsets.Select(set => element.Concat(set));
        return subsets.Concat(ignoreFirstSubsets);
    }
```

**3. Another recursive method...**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int target = 20;
        var numbers = new [] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 9 };
        var result = GetSubsets(numbers, target, "");

        foreach (var subset in result) Console.WriteLine($"{subset} = {target}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Combinations: {result.Count()}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSubsets(int[] set, int sum, string values)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
        {
            var left = sum - set[i];
            var vals = values != "" ? $"{set[i]} + {values}" : $"{set[i]}";
            if (left == 0) yield return vals;
            else
            {
                int[] possible = set.Take(i).Where(n => n <= sum).ToArray();
                if (possible.Length <= 0) continue;
                foreach (string s in GetSubsets(possible, left, vals)) yield return s;
            }
        }
    }
```

**4. Using binary search. Linear time.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int target = 20;
        var numbers = new [] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 9 };

        var subsets = GetSubsets(numbers, target);

        foreach (var s in subsets) Console.WriteLine($"{s} = {target}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Combinations: {subsets.Count()}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static IEnumerable<string> GetSubsets(int[] array, int target)
    {      
        Array.Sort((Array)array);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for (int i = array.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var eq = $"{array[i]}";
            var sum = array[i];
            var toAdd = 0;

            while (sum != target)
            {
                var mid = Array.BinarySearch(array, 0, sum <= target / 2 && sum != array[i] ? array.Length - 1 : i, target - sum);
                mid = mid < 0 ? ~mid - 1 : mid;
                if (mid == i  || mid < 0 || toAdd == array[mid] ) break;

                toAdd = array[mid];
                sum += array[mid];
                eq += $" + {array[mid]}";
                if (sum == target) result.Add(eq);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: All of the options are very slow for me. Is there any way to run them in parallel? I am testing it on a fairly powerful machine (128GB of RAM and 4 x Xeon Processors)

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion. Note that this solution will favor solutions that can be acquired by using the first items from the list. So for a target of `20`, you won’t get `12+8` as the solution but `5+7+8`.

```
List<int> findSum(List<int> numbers, int target, int index = 0)
{
    // loop through all numbers starting from the index
    for (var i = index; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        int remainder = target - numbers[i];
        // if the current number is too big for the target, skip
        if (remainder < 0)
            continue;
        // if the current number is a solution, return a list with it
        else if (remainder == 0)
            return new List<int>() { numbers[i] };
        else
        {
            // otherwise try to find a sum for the remainder later in the list
            var s = findSum(numbers, remainder, i + 1);

            // if no number was returned, we could’t find a solution, so skip
            if (s.Count == 0)
                continue;

            // otherwise we found a solution, so add our current number to it
            // and return the result
            s.Insert(0, numbers[i]);
            return s;
        }
    }

    // if we end up here, we checked all the numbers in the list and
    // found no solution
    return new List<int>();
}

void Main()
{
    List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 5, 7, 12, 8, 7 };

    Console.WriteLine(findSum(myList, 12)); // 5, 7
    Console.WriteLine(findSum(myList, 20)); // 5, 7, 8
    Console.WriteLine(findSum(myList, 31)); // 5, 7, 12, 7
}
```

Comment: What would you change in the code so that it would return the first result that is over or equal to the target?

Comment: @FrancisC The sum of _all_ numbers is likely the trivial solution to that problem (if a solution exists). A more useful goal might be to get the smallest subset which sum is larger or something like that. – If you want to use my code (which should give you the _first_ solution), then you should be able to combine the `if` and `else if` to return a solution as soon as the `remainder` is lower or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of mine in C# will return all combinations(including repetitive use of same number) that equals a given number.

```
string r;
List<int> l = new List<int>();
void u(int w, int s, int K, int[] A) { 
    // If a unique combination is found 
    if (s == K) { 
        r += "(" + String.Join(" ", l) + ")";
        return; 
    } 
    // For all other combinations
    for (int i=w; i<A.Length; i++){
        // Check if the sum exceeds K 
        int x = A[i];
        if (s + x <= K){
            l.Add(x);
            u(i, s + x, K,A);
            l.Remove(x);
        }
    }
} 
string combinationSum(int[] a, int s) {
    r = "";
    u(0, 0, s, a.Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray());
    return r.Any() ? r : "Empty";
}
```

for a: [2, 3, 5, 9] and s = 9

the result will be :
"(2 2 2 3)(2 2 5)(3 3 3)(9)"